# apache flink write data to separate hive cluster

Tags: hive, apache-flink

With [apache flink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/) is it possible to write to a hive cluster such that the cluster is able to distribute the data among his nodes?

Example as described [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/) seems to indicate data is intended to a HDFS on the apache flink node itself. But what options exist if you intend to have the HDFS on a separate cluster and not on the flink worker nodes?

Please bear with me, I am totally new to this topic and I could get something conceptually completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read from and write to Hive using Flink. There's an overview available at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hive/hive_read_write/

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at those docs already, where does it explain how to write to hdfs on another host? How can you specify the namenode?

Comment: I believe this is explained in the 'Connecting to Hive' section at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/#connecting-to-hive